# Regex expression to match tab

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a regular expression that matches tab symbol by the following rules:

```
"—>text"       does not match
"1.—>text"     does not match
"1—>text"      does not match
"A.—>text"     does not match
"text—>text"   match
```

That is, it shouldn't match tabs that are at the beginning of the text, after a listed item mark [A-Z] or [0-9]. Here is my expression:

```
(?<!^((?:\d+|[A-Z])(?:\.)?))\t(?!\1)
```

[https://regex101.com/r/zgJAG9/1](https://regex101.com/r/zgJAG9/1/)

It does not work for all cases:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<!^(?:(?:\d+|[A-Z])\.?)?)\t
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zgJAG9/2/). *Details*:

- `(?<!^(?:(?:\d+|[A-Z])\.?)?)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there are

  - `^` - start of string
  - `(?:(?:\d+|[A-Z])\.?)?` - an optional sequence of

    - `(?:\d+|[A-Z])` - one or more digits or an uppercase ASCII letter
    - `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\t` - a tab char.

Note that `(?:\.)?` is the same as `\.?`.

Also, capturing groups inside a negative lookbehind makes little sense as regex processing will be stopped before your backreference pattern is reached.